# Java JPanel repaint() issue?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, components

I'm kind of new to GUIs. I created this simple app that paints an oval with different color every time a button is pushed. but when ever I call the `JPanel`'s `repaint()` it doesn't just repaint the panel's portion of the frame (the oval). Instead, it kind of repaints the entire frame and it also paints the button that I clicked at the top of the frame (the northern border). I know I can simply call the `JFrame`'s `repaint()` to solve this problem, but I was just wondering why is this happening. I thought that all what `repaint()` does is simply call the `paintComponent()` of the object.
can somebody explain why is it behaving this way??
thanks!!

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Jbutton extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JFrame frame;
    JButton b;
    panel p;

    public void go() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        b = new JButton("click me");
        p = new panel();
        b.addActionListener(this);
        frame.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, p);
        frame.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, b);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(250, 250);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    class panel extends JPanel {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
            int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
            int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
            g.setColor(new Color(red, blue, green));
            g.fillOval(20, 30, 50, 50);
        }

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    p.repaint();

}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are calling `super.paintComponent` to prepare the `Graphics` context for painting

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g)
    int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    g.setColor(new Color(red, blue, green));
    g.fillOval(20, 30, 50, 50);
 }
```

The long and short of it is the `Graphics` context is a shared resource.  Every component painted during a paint cycle will share the same `Graphics` context, mean that what ever was previously painted to it will still be there.  You need to clear/prepare the `Graphics` context each time `paintComponent` is called.

This is essentially what `paintComponent` does...